# Oddity: Where's My Close Vote on This Question?

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-close, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Happened Here? Voted to Close 4 Days Ago, but No Close Votes Today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today)

The question [What are software practices in mission-critical industries (e.g. nuclear power plant)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071762/what-are-software-practices-in-mission-critical-industries-e-g-nuclear-power-p) currently shows a single close vote, but clicking the "Close" link says that I've already voted to close.

Clicking the Edit link shows that the question has been closed twice and reopened, but doesn't show me as one of the closers.

Just curious - what's going on with this, and how can I see the "real" history?

Comment: You probably had a close vote that aged away.

Comment: ...and I just noticed who the asker on the duplicate is. ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos Not the first time this has happened, oddly

Answer (score 1):

You voted to close and your vote expired.

Close/Re-open votes expire at a rate of one every 4 days, for questions with more than 100 views (they don't, for questions with 100 or less views).

Comment: I didn't know they expired so easily, no wonder the close votes queue is stuck!

Comment: Thanks. The second part of the question is: is there a way to _see_ that I voted and that the vote has aged away?

Comment: @JohnSaunders No, unfortunately.